# Storing an array of a different type into a jagged array

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays

Does an array stored inside a jagged array need to be of the same type? for example can I store an array of ints and an array of strings in one jagged array?

Comment: No, you may not do that. What are you trying to do? There has to be a better alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use an array of objects ? here is an example-

```
        var jaggedArray = new object[3];
        jaggedArray[0] = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        jaggedArray[1] = new[] { "str", "onemore" };
        jaggedArray[2] = new[] { new { prop = 14 }, new { prop = 12 }, new { prop = 1 } };
        Console.Write(jaggedArray[0].ToString());
```

Copy & paste this in a console application and have a breakpoint on Console.Write, you can see the built array in quick watch window.

Comment: But then you'll get a mess when you try to do something with it in most practical situations. Anyway, this answers the question :) to the level they requested (is it or is it not possible).

Comment: @MarcelN. - I was trying to demonstrate the capability, indeed its a bad design to use it internally, but who knows if the iConqueror want to return some JSON in his service method !