# How do I create a method for filling a matrix without knowing the type of the input

Tags: c#, matrix

I want to create a method that reads input from the console and fills it, example:

> 3 4
>
> A B B D
>
> E B B B
>
> I J B B

The first line reads the dimensions and the rest are the input in the matrix (there is no empty line in between i just cant paste it otherwise).
I wrote this :

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        char[,] matrix = ReadAndFillMatrix(input);
    }

  private static char[,] ReadAndFillMatrix(string input)
        {
            var size=input.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
.Select(int.Parse)
.ToArray();
            var rows = size[0];
            var cols = size[1];
            var matrix = new char[rows, cols];
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                var line = Console.ReadLine()
               .Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
               .Select(char.Parse)
               .ToArray();
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                {
                    matrix[i, j] = line[j];
                }
            }

            return matrix;
        }
```

So far so good, but what do I do when the matrix is not made of chars, but of integers for example?

**The question:** Do I have to create a different method for each type of matrix or is there some something I'm missing?

PS: I want to be able to use it in multiple places for different matrices not just the one

Comment: How about using a generic type? Like say, a var?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close! Just use [`Char.IsDigit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t641e58(v=vs.110).aspx) (or `int.TryParse`) to test each of the sections you've read out, and that way you'll know; of course, you'll need to create a different matrix array for each type `char` and `int` for example, but that shouldn't be too onerous.

---

## Edit

As per the comment made by @kokosaish on this answer, I've updated to the following:

```
void Main()
{
    var stringMatrix = ReadAndFillMatrix<string>(s => s);
    var intMatrix = ReadAndFillMatrix<int>(int.Parse);
    var doubleMatrix = ReadAndFillMatrix<double>(double.Parse);
}

private static T[,] ReadAndFillMatrix<T>(Func<string,T> sectionParser)
{
    var readAndSplit =
        new Func<string[]>(
            () =>
            {
                return
                Console.ReadLine()
                .Split(new char[] { ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .ToArray();
            });
            
    var size = readAndSplit();
    var rows = int.Parse(size[0]);
    var cols = int.Parse(size[1]);
    
    var matrix = new T[rows, cols];
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        var line = readAndSplit();
        for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            matrix[i,j] = sectionParser(line[j]);
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

This is far from production ready code, as you need to add error handling for when parsing fails etc, but this should show you how to specify which type you want.

Comment: But i need to specify the type i return in the method.Even if i found out that the matrix was made of ints and not chars I've declared that the method is char[,] that means that i should only return char[,], does it not ?

Comment: @kokosaish I've updated the answer, this will now allow you to create a matrix of any type you like, provided that you can perform a parse operation to that particular type.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a jagged array of type var. Check this question for the solution.

[Storing an array of a different type into a jagged array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25091947/storing-an-array-of-a-different-type-into-a-jagged-array)

In that array, you can store each row as a new array. And that will happen at runtime, so you can do a TypeOf to find the exact type of data. Or you can keep it all as var.